# Why is NodeJS only showing files on my browser instead of the results of my code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I'm new into node JS. I'm trying to install node and run just a 'Hello World' app but I have problems with my server.

When I try to run my app, the server is showing only the index files and not 'Hello World'.  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3fPV.png)

The node server is working and says that the http-server is available.

My code for my Hello World app:

```
var http = require("http");

http.createServer(function(req, res){
  response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});

  response.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(8080);

console.log('Server running at http://192.168.178.14:8080/');
```

I want to run the file 'index.js' (second file in first screenshot). How can I fix this?

Comment: Looks like you already have an *ecstatic* server running on :8080

Comment: No, there is only one instance running.

Comment: @user3507281 please look better at the error page, it says at the bottom that it's generated by _"ecstatic server"_.

Comment: Try clicking on the `index.js` link. It says "92B" on the screenshot, but the code you posted is 200+ bytes long. Which means the `index.js` that the server is using is not the same as the one you're editing. Clicking on it should open the source code, it might help you understand what is going on

Comment: I'm closing this as off-topic, since the given code does not reproduce the problem. Please revise with a [mcve], as you have pointed out that the given code does _not_ error with `EADDRINUSE` and changing the port always causes the `ecstatic` server to run. Obviously your script is the culprit, given the symptoms, and you're not sharing the code you're actually running.

Answer (score 1):

As [Mikael Lennholm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2236921/mikael-lennholm) and [robertklep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/893780/robertklep) have mentioned in the comments, the issue is that you are trying to run a second server on the same address (`:8080`).

I tested this myself to make sure, and here's the results I got:

[image: ecstatic server]

Running an instance of the [ecstatic](https://github.com/jfhbrook/node-ecstatic) server on `:8080`, producing a very similar image to yours (using default code provided by ecstatic's documentation).

---

[image: standard server]

Attempting to run a regular server on the `:8080` port gives me an error, `EADDRINUSE :::8080` (which is expected, as the other application is already using that address). You should probably get this error when trying to run your application as well.

---

Now, either you or someone else is to blame. But the fact is that there *is already* a server running on port `8080`. I'd reccomend you try to find out who set it up (if it wasn't yourself) or maybe just try using another port. For example, `8088`:

[image: both servers]

Comment: The mystery is that I've changed the port several times. I tried 8081 and several others. The result is always the same.